# String.split() method bug in GWT 2.0.3

Tags: string, gwt, gwt2

I'm upgrading a GWT project from GWT 1.7.1 to currently newest version 2.0.3. It seems that new GWT broke String.split(String regex) method - I get the following error on the Javascript side:

```
this$static is undefined
```

This happens in this line of my .nocache.js file:

```
if (maxMatch == 0 && this$static.length > 0) {
```

...which happens to be a part of String split method equivalent in Javascript.

Is there a cure for this, apart from doing string splitting myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible workaround is to write a JSNI method that wraps around the standard JavaScript `split` function, something like this (note: code not tested :))

```
public static final native String[] split(String string, String separator) /*-{
    return string.split(separator);
}-*/;
```

The closest thing on the [GWT Issues list](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+split&utf8=%E2%9C%93) is [Issue 3071](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/3077), but I'd just stick with JSNI on this one (just like I stick with JSNI for regular expressions).

Comment: Thanks! This works, with minor correction that return argument must be String[] instead of JsArrayString.

Comment: Heh, thanks for reporting back - I've corrected the code above. I guess JSNI is not that "stupid" (JsArray* classes are usually used with JavaScript Overlay Objects, so I thought that this would be the case here too).

Comment: these seems such a weird thing to missing from the emulation library